# Log4j exclude particular files in a package

Tags: java, log4j

I have a log file for the entire project, but now I wanted to exclude a particular class file log from the default log and write into a separate file. There are around 100 of class files in the project. This class file which I wanted to log separately is inside a package of 15 files.

I have tried setting  but it doesn't work. Is there a way I can do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a separate logger and appender for that class.

For example suppose you have 3 classes in a package and you want one of them to write to a different log file. In the example below the class `Example2` will write to its own file while the `Example1` and `Example3` classes will write to another file.

Example1.java:

```
package my;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Example1 {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Example1.class);

    public static void main(String[] args){
        logger.info("info from my.Example1");

        Example2 e2 = new Example2();
        e2.doSomething();

        Example3 e3 = new Example3();
        e3.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Example2.java

```
package my;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Example2 {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Example2.class);

    public void doSomething(){
        logger.info("This is from Example2 class");
    }
}
```

Example3.java:

```
package my;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Example3 {
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Example3.class);

    public void doSomething(){
        logger.info("This is from Example3 class");
    }
}
```

log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file1, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.appender.file1=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file1.File=logs/file1.log
log4j.appender.file1.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file1.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file1.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n

log4j.appender.file2=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file2.File=logs/file2.log
log4j.appender.file2.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file2.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file2.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n

log4j.logger.my.Example2=INFO, file2, stdout
log4j.additivity.my.Example2=false
```

Here is the output:

file1.log:

```
INFO main my.Example1 - info from my.Example1
INFO main my.Example3 - This is from Example3 class
```

file2.log:

```
INFO main my.Example2 - This is from Example2 class
```

Comment: May I know how this can be written in xml format (I'm using log4j.xml).

Currently in my XML Config is like below


            <logger name="com.my" additivity="false">
  <level value="debug" />
  <appender-ref ref="ALL_LOG" />
    </logger>
 
 

 <logger name="com.my.xmlrpc.process" additivity="false">
  <level value="debug" />
  <appender-ref ref="ALL_LOG" />
 </logger>


what I wanted to exclude is one java class file from package com.my.xmlrpc.process, file name is com.my.xmlrpc.process.ProcesssTime

Comment: `<logger name="com.my.xmlrpc.process.ProcesssTime" additivity="false"> <level value="debug" /> <appender-ref ref="OTHER LOG" /> </logger>` but you will have to define the new appender as well, which you can do by copying the one you have and changing the name and the file name it writes to.

Comment: when I create a new appender the logs will be printed in the new file (OTHER_LOG) and also it will be appended in ALL_LOG also .. I only wanted in OTHER_LOG not in ALL_LOG.
     
Here is my appender 
        <appender name="OTHER LOG" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
  <param name="File" value="${catalina.base}/OTHER LOG" />
  <param name="DatePattern" value="'-'yyyyMMddHHmm'-Results.log'" />   
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
  <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p [%t]-[%C:%M()] %m%n" />
  </layout> </appender>